# Trying to load in text files separately to python and perform the same calculation on each of them

Tags: python, loops, text-files

I have 12 text files that consist of the points of 12 different runs of a random walk function that I had previously saved as

```
'file' + str(j) 
for j in range(12)
```

I now wish to load each text file into my code, and then perform the following on it:

```
np.argmax((filej[:, 0]) > 10)
```

To find how many steps it takes each of the walks to reach x = 10.
The only way I have managed to do it so far is the following:

```
    filename = 'file1'
if os.path.exists(filename): 
    file1 = np.loadtxt(filename)
np.argmax((file1[:, 0]) > 10)
```

This works, but it means I have to do that separately for each file (which there is 12 of) so is quite time consuming and not very tidy. Is there a way that I can do this all in one? And then possibly create a list or an array of each of the values for the 12 text files for

```
np.argmax((filej[:, 0]) > 10)
```

, perhaps using some sort of loop?

Answer (score 0):

I'd put the filenames in a list then construct a dict with the filename as key and your processed value as value.

```py
files = ["file1", "file2",]

data = {}

for file in files:
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        content = file.read()
        # compute your value
        data[file] = value
```